# Connecting multiplexer/demultiplexer input to Vcc of the same chip. Will this cause any performance issues?

Tags: digital-logic, analog, multiplexer, analog-switch

In one of my circuits, I am connecting the I/P pin of multiplexer/demultiplexer to Vcc (5V) as shown below. I have 2 questions.

When switching, will the current draw cause performance deviations in this connection?

Can I connect the EN signal (coming from an Arduino) to D also instead of connecting to supply?

[image]

Comment: How much current you need? If driving transistors, are you sure 10k is strong enougn to turn transistors on? What is the circuitry on the AIN_RELx_EN pins?

Comment: My relay coil current is 40ma and the base current l set is 4ma.The circuitry at enable pin is a jumper it will be installed and during turn on chip will be disabled

Comment: Please note that your 10k resistor will not be able to provide 4mA of base current.

Comment: IS or ID (CONT) Source or drain continuous current (Sx, D) is 30 mA.I am planning to add 200ohms as pull up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any significant current drawn from any of the switch pins, the datasheet specifies an absolute maximum of 30 milliamperes for any pin.

This goes for both questions 1 & 2.

If the device is used within its rated current limits, connecting the input D to VCC permanently shall not affect the normal operation of the device. The resistor added will even make it tolerate the situation where one of the 'S' terminals is held low by an external circuit so the device will try to drive the 'D' terminal low. The resistor will limit the current sunk in this situation.